# How do I sort a table based on multiple levels in SQL?

Tags: sql, multi-level

I have a BOM to sort as shown in the attached picture and I cannot seem to be able to sort mulitlevel in SQL. 
in this list Child can be parent.
Position seems to be a good way but look at Poition 3. there are two of them when the level changes. (Could if be wrong Join?)
Level is the level of the item. it is consistent.
I would appreciate if someone can assist.

---

Wrong (unsorted) table

```
itemSpecID  +  ParentID  +  ChildID  +  Position  +  Level  +  ItemSpecStrucID  +  ItemNo         +
151382      +  151382    +  150776   +  17        +  1      +  469912           +  FOAM-KIT-00595 +
151382      +  151382    +  151383   +  0         +  1      +  469908           +  CHAR-FRM-00708 +
151382      +  151383    +  151372   +  2         +  2      +  469916           +  HDWR-MIS-00024
151382      +  151383    +  151373   +  3         +  2      +  469917           +  HDWR-MIS-00025
151382      +  151383    +  151374   +  4         +  2      +  469918           +  HDWR-MIS-00026
151382      +  151383    +  151384   +  1         +  2      +  469915           +  HDWR-MIS-00023
151382      +  151382    +  151344   +  4         +  1      +  469910           +  SRVC-GEN-00014
151382      +  151382    +  149441   +  5         +  1      +  469911           +  PANL-BAK-00284
151382      +  151382    +  149079   +  3         +  1      +  469909           +  PANL-SAT-00300
151382      +  151382    +  150765   +  18        +  1      +  469913           +  HDWR-BRK-00015
151382      +  151382    +  150810   +  20        +  1      +  469914           +  FABR-DOUX-00004
```

---

Final Sorting needed

```
itemSpecID  +  ParentID  +  ChildID  +  Position  +  Level  +  ItemSpecStrucID  +  ItemNo
151382      +  151382    +  151383   +  0         +  1      +  469908           +  CHAR-FRM-00708
151382      +  151383    +  151384   +  1         +  2      +  469915           +  HDWR-MIS-00023
151382      +  151383    +  151372   +  2         +  2      +  469916           +  HDWR-MIS-00024
151382      +  151383    +  151373   +  3         +  2      +  469917           +  HDWR-MIS-00025
151382      +  151383    +  151374   +  4         +  2      +  469918           +  HDWR-MIS-00026
151382      +  151382    +  149079   +  3         +  1      +  469909           +  PANL-SAT-00300
151382      +  151382    +  151344   +  4         +  1      +  469910           +  SRVC-GEN-00014
151382      +  151382    +  149441   +  5         +  1      +  469911           +  PANL-BAK-00284
151382      +  151382    +  150776   +  17        +  1      +  469912           +  FOAM-KIT-00595
151382      +  151382    +  150765   +  18        +  1      +  469913           +  HDWR-BRK-00015
151382      +  151382    +  150810   +  20        +  1      +  469914           +  FABR-DOUX-00004
```

---

[image: Item BOM looks like]

Comment: Please check your second table is not a sorted one.

Comment: I fund a column in my tables that did the trick for me. Is there a way of deleting this question? I do not want anyone searching and finding a question without a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a column in my tables that helped me sort the way I want. unfortunately, this question will not benefit anyone and I found no way of deleting this question.